# Using "or" or "nor" with three options

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation, negation, informal-language

Which of these sentences is correct?

> 1. Don't you ever call me "honey". ***Nor*** "sweetheart", ***nor*** "my dear".
> 2. Don't you ever call me "honey". ***Or*** "sweetheart", ***or*** "my dear".
> 3. Don't you ever call me "honey", ***nor*** "sweetheart", ***nor*** "my dear".
> 4. Don't you ever call me "honey", ***or*** "sweetheart", ***or*** "my dear".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 4 sounds natural to my (American) ear.  It is informal.  The emphasis is on the word "ever".

> Don't you ever call me "Honey", or "Sweetheart", or "My dear".

A very formal way to say this is:

> My name is neither "Honey", nor "Sweetheart", nor "My dear".

Comment: Thanks. And what about options 1 and 2? Do I understand correctly that the first option is corrent (although informal) and the second one is wrong?

Comment: Option 2 is even less formal than option 4.   I would not be surprised to hear option 2, though.  Option 2 sounds choppier than option 4.  Options 1 and 3 do not sound natural -- people who say "nor" tend to speak formally.